# magento convert template tag

Tags: php, magento

I have saved some html using WYSIWYG editor:

```
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/image.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
```

Now I want to convert it together with the full path of the image in admin/frontend.
How I can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve that by passing the templated string like below:

```
<?php 
$string='<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/image.png"}}" alt="" /></p>';
echo $this->helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($string)
?>
```

First same code was not working but later it started working automatically.